Time complexity calculation for algorithms with nested while loops
I'm trying to figure out the time complexity of the following program. So far, my calculations yield that the worst case time complexity would be O(n^3).
for i in range(1, n):
  j = 1
  while j < i*i:
    j += 1

My method involved creating a table and calculating the number of "runs" for each loop.
So for any arbitrary N, the outer loop is going to loop around (N-1) times and the inner loop is going to loop around a total of ((N-1)/2)*(0+(N-1)^2 - 1), I used the arithmetic progression summation formula here. Adding them up yielded the O(n^3) complexity.
I guess what I'm trying to ask is whether it is possible for an algorithm to have O(n^3) complexity with just two loops. I think it should theoretically be possible is time complexity is just an estimation of how the running time of an algorithm is proportional to input size, however, I haven't seen such an algorithm yet where two loops result in such an answer.

The time complexity of O(n3) . This is possible because, while there are only two loops, the number of iterations of the inner loop increases quadratically with respect to the index of the outer loop. Thus, when summed up over all iterations of the outer loop, it results in a cubic time complexity.

O(n³) is correct.
Complexity is not directly connected to the number of nested loops, even is this is often a good indicator ;-) .
e.g.
for i in range(1, n*n*n*n*n*n):
  a++;

has O(n⁶) with only 1 loop.
